# CSS causing lag on scroll

Tags: html, css

The following CSS causes lagg when I want to scroll down on my page, the first time it loads:

```
.main.style2 {
    background-color: #333;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
    background-image: url(../images/overlay1.png), url(../images/header.jpg);
    background-size: auto, cover;
    height: auto;
}
```

What would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Elise! A more thorough explanation of what you mean by buggy will help people answer your question. It's not clear currently if scrolling down first is "buggy" or after pressing your scroll to top button it's "buggy". Does buggy mean that it jumps to the top immediately or  does it mean if feels like it lags when it scrolls to the top or something else?

Comment: After the page is loaded and you start to scroll down, the scrolling gets interrupted because the arrow is loading, after it appeared, everything is smooth again :) but that first interruption does not look professional, edited my question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the problem is with arrow. then try :
hiding arrow with your pure css code.
then on document ready with jquery try changing css to show it.

Comment: I just noticed that the arrow isnt the problem, also no js is causing it, what else could be the problem?

Comment: do you have it online somewhere so I can check it?

Comment: I would suggest a fixed height for you element rather than auto.

Comment: Changed height to 100% but the problem is still there

Comment: dear @Elise it is realy hard to say without observing. but these may help: try to add a rgb color rather than rgba.